# Image cannot be displayed in header.ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I'm making a website and I thought it would be cool to have a jvascript http header(via express) so I woundnt have to create a header and a footer on every file. Okay, I did that(Yayyy) but I have to insert a logo(jpeg) into the header and I cannot because somethings wrong......but I dont know wha.

My header.ejs file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale">

            <title>Document</title>

            <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/Header.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="Header">
                <div id="upper-Header">
                    <img src="../public/img/upper-header.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div id="lower-Header">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My app.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;


app.use(express.static("./src/public"));
app.use("/css/", express.static(__dirname  + "public/css/"));
app.use("/img/", express.static(__dirname  + "public/img/"));
app.use("/js/", express.static(__dirname  + "public/js/"));


app.set("views", "./src/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.get("", (req, res) => {
    res.render("Header", { text: "This is ejs"});
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening for port: ${port}`);
});
```

````
node_modules
src
   public
       css
         Header.css
         Footer.css
      img
         upper-header.jpg
      js
         Footer.js
         Header.js
  views
     Header.ejs
     Footer.ejs
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json```
````

Answer (score 0):

The name of image is `upper-Header.jpg` while you have set it `upper-header.jpg` in you ejs file. Try after correcting the name.

Comment: ya, that was a typo in the question, both of them say upper-header.jpg. Sorry bout that